# C: gcc implicitly converts signed char to unsigned char and vice versa?

Tags: c, gcc, types

I'm trying to learn C at got stuck with datatype-sizes at the moment.

Have a look at this code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    char a = 255;
    char b = -128;
    a = -128;
    b = 255;
    printf("size: %lu\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("min: %d\n", CHAR_MIN);
    printf("max: %d\n", CHAR_MAX);
}
```

The printf-output is:

```
size: 1
min: -128
max: 127
```

How is that possible? The size of char is 1 Byte and the default char seems to be signed (-128...127). So how can I assign a value > 127 without getting an overflow warning (which I get when I try to assign -128 or 256)? Is gcc automatically converting to unsigned char? And then, when I assign a negative value, does it convert back? Why does it do so? I mean, all this implicitness wouldn't make it easier to understand.

EDIT:

Okay, it's not converting anything:

```
char a = 255;
char b = 128;
printf("%d\n", a);    /* -1 */
printf("%d\n", b);    /* -128 */
```

So it starts counting from the bottom up. But why doesn't the compiler give me a warning? And why does it so, when I try to assign 256?

Comment: Who said it converts it? It could just be assigning crazy stuff.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour on the overflow perhaps

Comment: @Tony: no UB here; just implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: @Tony The Tiger: It's not undefined behavior, it's either assigns an implementation-defined value or it raises an implementation-defined signal.

Comment: +1 This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See 6.3.1.3/3 in [the C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256/pdf)

> ... the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So, if you don't get a signal (if your program doesn't stop) read the documentation for your compiler to understand what it does.

---

`gcc` documents the behaviour ( in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation ) as

> - The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 6.3.1.3).
>
> > For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

Comment: So I can assume they have their reasons for doing so. Maybe it has something to do with working with two's complement integers.

Answer (score 4):

> how can I assign a value > 127

The result of converting an out-of-range integer value to a signed integer type is either an implementation-defined result or an implementation-defined signal (6.3.1.3/3). So your code is legal C, it just doesn't have the same behavior on all implementations.

> without getting an overflow warning

It's entirely up to GCC to decide whether to warn or not about valid code. I'm not quite sure what its rules are, but I get a warning for initializing a `signed char` with `256`, but not with `255`. I guess that's because a warning for code like `char a = 0xFF` would normally not be wanted by the programmer, even when char is signed. There is a portability issue, in that the same code on another compiler might raise a signal or result in the value `0` or `23`.

`-pedantic` enables a warning for this (thanks, pmg), which makes sense since `-pedantic` is intended to help write portable code. Or arguably doesn't make sense, since as R.. points out it's beyond the scope of merely putting the compiler into standard-conformance mode. However, the man page for gcc says that `-pedantic` enables diagnostics required by the standard. This one isn't, but the man page also says:

> Some users try to use -pedantic to check programs for strict ISO C
>   conformance.  They soon find that it does not do quite what they want:
>   it finds some non-ISO practices, but not all---only those for which
>   ISO C requires a diagnostic, and some others for which diagnostics
>   have been added.

This leaves me wondering what a "non-ISO practice" is, and suspecting that `char a = 255` is one of the ones for which a diagnostic has been specifically added. Certainly "non-ISO" means more than just things for which the standard demands a diagnostic, but gcc obviously is not going so far as to diagnose all non-strictly-conforming code of this kind.

I also get a warning for initializing an `int` with `((long long)UINT_MAX) + 1`, but not with `UINT_MAX`. Looks as if by default gcc consistently gives you the first power of 2 for free, but after that it thinks you've made a mistake.

Use `-Wconversion` to get a warning about all of those initializations, including `char a = 255`. Beware that will give you a boatload of other warnings that you may or may not want.

> all this implicitness wouldn't make it easier to understand

You'll have to take that up with Dennis Ritchie. C is weakly-typed as far as arithmetic types are concerned. They all implicitly convert to each other, with various levels of bad behavior when the value is out of range depending on the types involved. Again, `-Wconversion` warns about the dangerous ones.

There are other design decisions in C that mean the weakness is quite important to avoid unwieldy code. For example, the fact that arithmetic is always done in at least an `int` means that `char a = 1, b = 2; a = a + b` involves an implicit conversion from `int` to `char` when the result of the addition is assigned to `a`. If you use `-Wconversion`, or if C didn't have the implicit conversion at all, you'd have to write `a = (char)(a+b)`, which wouldn't be too popular. For that matter, `char a = 1` and even `char a = 'a'` are both implicit conversions from `int` to `char`, since C has no literals of type `char`. So if it wasn't for all those implicit conversions either various other parts of the language would have to be different, or else you'd have to absolutely litter your code with casts. Some programmers want strong typing, which is fair enough, but you don't get it in C.

Comment: I think simply `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic ...` or `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic ...` also produce a warning about the specific overflow

Comment: @pmg: that's useful. I suppose if you're not using `-pedantic`, then you're not writing code intended to port to other compilers. At least, that's my rule, others may disagree.

Comment: `-pedantic` doesn't warn for `int i = UINT_MAX;`, though. I'm a bit confused about the rationale here.

Comment: my gcc expands `UINT_MAX` to `(2147483647 * 2U + 1U)` which does not produce a warning; using `4294967295` instead produces the warning !! ... and `4294967295U` doesn't warn.

Comment: `-pedantic` tells gcc to warn or give errors about things the standard requires the compiler to warn or give errors about, and **completely valid** implicit conversions are not one of those things.

Comment: @R..: that is not all that `-pedantic` tells gcc to do (see recent edit to my answer), although possibly it should be.

Comment: So the difference (versus what I said) is that `gcc -pedantic` also warns for some things that are not valid C, but for which the standard does not require a diagnostic?

Comment: @R..: I don't know, because I don't know what "non-ISO practices" is supposed to mean. If it means what you say, things that aren't valid C, then there's a bug either in the man page or in the compiler, since they don't correspond. But the sentence before says, "Some users try to use -pedantic to check programs for strict ISO C conformance", and a program that does `char a = 255` is not strictly conforming, so I think they're justified if they want to claim that "non-ISO practices" means "non-strictly-conforming code", based on that paragraph of the man page taken together.

Comment: I've quoted the whole para now, for completeness and in case it varies by gcc version and/or distro. I think most people would say that relying on UB is a "non-ISO practice" even though it's valid C and might work perfectly reliably on gcc using extra guarantees of that implementation. So I really can't tell quite where they mean to draw the line regarding implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: How is `printf("%d", INT_MAX)` not strictly conforming?

Comment: @R.. because its behavior is implemention-defined, specifically it outputs different bytes depending on the implementation-defined value of `INT_MAX`. Or does that not count as implementation-defined since it's defined given the value of `INT_MAX`? Anyway I've already removed that example from my comment, I don't think I was adding anything by pointing out that people writing strictly conforming programs are fairly rare even among those writing portable code.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution** :

see signed char can have value from -128 to 127 okey
so now when you are assigning 129 to any char value it will  take 
127(this is valid) + 2(this additional) = -127
(give char a=129 & print it value comes -127)

look char register can have value like..
...126,127,-128,-127,-126...-1,0,1,2....

which ever you will assign final value will come by this calculation ...!!